# Randomly select n elements from Array

Tags: scala, random

I want to select **n** unique elements from array where size of my array is normally **1000** and value of **n** is **3**. I want to implement this in iterative algorithm where iterations are around **3000000** and I have to get n unique elements in each iteration. Here are some available solutions I fond but I can not use them due to their draw backs as discussed below.

```
import scala.util.Random
val l = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
val ran = l.map(x => (Random.nextFloat(), x)).sortBy(_._1).map(_._2).take(3)
```

This method is slower as have to create **three** arrays and Sorting the array too.

```
 val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
 val uniq = list.distinct
 val shuffled = scala.util.Random.shuffle(uniq)
 val sampled = shuffled.take(n)
```

Two arrays are generated and Shuffling the large array is slower process.

```
 val arr = Array.fill(1000)(math.random )
 for (i <- 1 to n; r = (Math.random * xs.size).toInt) yield arr(r)
```

This is faster tecnique but some times returns same element more than one time. Here is an output.

```
val xs = List(60, 95, 24, 85, 50, 62, 41, 68, 34, 57)
for (i <- 1 to n; r = (Math.random * xs.size).toInt) yield xs(r)

res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector( 24 , 24 , 41)
```

It can be observed that **24** is returned **2 times**.

How can I change last method to get unique elements? Is there any other more optimal way to perform same task?

Comment: Does the ordering of the index of the 3 elements have to be random or could they, for example, be sorted?

Comment: @Tim random ordering

Comment: I asked this because solutions involving making a `Set` of values will apply an ordering of some sort when the values come out again so they won't technically be random.

Comment: Have a look at the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle).  Run it for the first three iterations and use the three elements selected.  No point in shuffling the whole array if you only want to pick three.

Comment: @rossum That algorithm requires either mutating the original array, which may not be possible, or creating a new array with every index in it, which is going to be slow. But do post the code as an answer so we can compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a recursive routine that does the job more efficiently than the other answers.

It builds a list of indices and then checks that the values are distinct. In the rare cases where there are duplicates, these are removed and new values added until there is a distinct set of indices.

The other answers check that the list is distinct each time an element is added.

```
def randomIndices(arraySize: Int, nIndices: Int): List[Int] = {
  def loop(done: Int, res: List[Int]): List[Int] =
    if (done < nIndices) {
      loop(done + 1, (Math.random * arraySize).toInt +: res)
    } else {
      val d = res.distinct
      val dSize = d.size

      if (dSize < nIndices) {
        loop(dSize, d)
      } else {
        res
      }
    }

  if (nIndices > arraySize) {
    randomIndices(arraySize, arraySize)
  } else {
    loop(0, Nil)
  }
}

randomIndices(xs.size, 3).map(xs)
```

This should be efficient when the number of elements is small compared to the size of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Your examples don't seem to be related (Strings? Ints?) but maybe something like this will work.

```
import scala.util.Random.nextInt

val limit = 1000  // 0 to 999 inclusive
val n = 3
Iterator.iterate(Set.fill(n)(nextInt(limit)))(_ + nextInt(limit))
        .dropWhile(_.size < n)
        .next()
//res0: Set[Int] = Set(255, 426, 965)
```

Comment: Use `ListSet` if you want the result to be truly random. Using `Set` makes some sequences impossible because the elements are not ordered.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of the Fisher-Yates shuffle.  It does not modify the original array, instead it shuffles an array of indices into the original array.  A lot of problems can be solved by adding a layer of indirection.  It does not shuffle the whole array, it just shuffles `num` items from the array.

I do not know scala, so this is pseudocode:

```
partShuffle(num, originalArray)

  // 1. Make a copy of the original array's indices.
  indexAry <- new Array(originalArray.length)
  for (i <- 0; i < originalArray.length; i++)
    indexAry[i] <- i
  end for

  // 2. Shuffle num random unique indices to the front.
  for (i <- 0; i < num; i++)
    // 2.1 New pick from the unpicked part of the array.
    currentPick <- i + random(originalArray.length - i)

    // 2.2 Swap the current pick to the front of the array.
    temp <- indexAry[i]
    indexAry[i] <- indexAry[currentPick]
    indexAry[currentPick] <- temp
  end for

  // 3. Build the return array.
  returnAry <- new Array(num)
  for (i <- 0; i < num; i++)
    returnAry[i] <- originalAry[indexAry[i]]
  end for

  return returnAry

end partShuffle()
```

As you pick an index, it is swapped to the front of the index array and excluded from further picks.  The first pick comes from [0..size-1]; the second pick comes from [1..size-1]; the third pick from [2..size-1] and so on.  The selected indices from the original array are returned in a shorter array, length `num`.

Assumptions:

- arrays are zero based
- `indexAry` is an array of integers
- `returnAry` is the same type as `originalAry`
- `random()` is seeded elsewhere in the code
- `random(x)` returns an integer from 0 (inclusive) to x (exclusive)

Answer (score -1):

You could generate random indexes between bounds. Generate the bound values by *logically* splitting the List into n parts.

Example: Given a list of 100 elements and n is 3, the bounds would be
(0,32)
(33,65)
(66,99)

```
  // Gets random int between "start" and "end"
  def randomInt(start: Int, end: Int): Int =
    start + scala.util.Random.nextInt((end - start) + 1)

  // Generates random int; given limit, total number of chunks and nth chunk
  def randomIntN(limit: Int, n: Int, nth: Int): Int =
    randomInt(
      (((limit / n) * nth) - (limit / n)),
      (((limit / n) * nth) - (if (n == nth) 0 else 1))
    )

  // Generate sequence
  for (
    i <- 1 to n;
    r = randomIntN(xs.size, n, i)
  ) yield xs(r)
```

Here are some of the outputs

```
res4: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(60, 50, 57)
res5: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(60, 85, 34)
res6: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(24, 50, 41)
```

Comment: This isn't random; you will always have one value from each of the ranges.

Comment: A random value from each of the ranges. But I get you.